# column vise data from excel for selected values in PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I'm having below Excel in SharePoint.

| ID | Name | College | Department | ... etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| F4505 | Ligum | VIT |  |  |
| S2304 | Limat |  | CS |  |

I want to create student view page in PowerApps.
In first page, I'm having gallery using ID and in OnSelect having below value,

```
Select(Parent);Navigate(preview,ScreenTransition.CoverRight,{selected_id:Gallery1.Selected.ID})
```

In preview page I'm getting selected Id by below code:

```
selected_id
```

But in Preview I need to display all the values of that Id number, which column having values. For example:

For **selected_id = F4505**

| ID | Name | College |
| --- | --- | --- |
| F4505 | Ligum | VIT |

For **selected_id = S2304**

| ID | Name | Department |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S2304 | Limat | CS |

Excel having 'N' number of columns and it may change. Im new to PowerApps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a form in the preview screen, you can set a condition to each card's Visible property to check if the field has a value. Similarly, you can show hide labels in your Gallery too. However this requires that the relevant cards, labels or other elements are already added by you for the given field.

Thus, having a changing number of columns in a data source will be a difficulty. PowerApps will not dynamically add display elements for your data sources. You will have to edit and republish your app whenever the data schema changes.

[Reza Dorani explored handling dynamic schema](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQqetH2QLyk), but I definitely recommend finalizing the schema first and relying on the functionality Power Apps provides out of the box.